# SQL Server taking values from 2 different tables with no matching and insert into 3rd table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `BusinessSector5` and `SubCategory` and I want to insert their IDs into a third table `Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5`. This 3rd table contains two columns `SubCategoryID` and `BusinessSector5ID`

I am using this query but it's not working

```
Insert into Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5(SubCategoryID, BusinessSector5ID)
values(
select SubCategory.ID,[BusinessSector5].ID

from [BusinessSector5],SubCategory

where Description_DE = 'Abbrucharbeiten' and Kategorie = 'Abbruch / Entsorgung')
```

I am getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword select.

Comment: You have not written any join condition for BusinessSector5 and SubCategory..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use VALUES when you are inserting using INSERT...SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5 (SubCategoryID, BusinessSector5ID)
SELECT SubCategory.ID, [BusinessSector5].ID
FROM [BusinessSector5], SubCategory
WHERE
  Description_DE = 'Abbrucharbeiten'
  AND Kategorie = 'Abbruch / Entsorgung'
```

but are you sure you don't need a JOIN between `BusinessSector5` and `SubCategory`? Maybe you need this:

```
INSERT INTO Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5 (SubCategoryID, BusinessSector5ID)
VALUES
((SELECT SubCategory.ID FROM SubCategory WHERE ....),
 (SELECT [BusinessSector5].ID FROM BusinessSector5 WHERE ....));
```

Comment: Yes I am sure because there are no matching values between both tables I just want to use these IDs some where else.

Comment: @Cami okay, you are actually doing a cartesian join, but i think that the second syntax should be correct, it will extract a value from subcategory and another value from businesssector5 and insert both values in Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5

Comment: @Cami you're welcome :) of course, you have to make sure that both queries return just one row

Comment: Thanks again Man!! there were few records repeating and now I fixed that. You saved me from a big mess :) ..

Answer (score 1):

You don't use "values" with select:

```
Insert into Match_Subcategory_BusinessSector5 (
    SubCategoryID,
    BusinessSector5ID
)
select 
    SubCategory.ID,
    [BusinessSector5].ID
from [BusinessSector5],SubCategory
where Description_DE = 'Abbrucharbeiten' 
    and Kategorie = 'Abbruch / Entsorgung'
```